# How to capture the logs for Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

I have created a premium tier Azure Redis Cache and i wanted to see logs such as from which IP, port the azure redis cache is being accessed etc. I know we have metrics option to view Cache Hits, Misses etc but i want to see the in detail information (IP, Port).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply issue a [client list](https://redis.io/commands/client-list) command against your cache to get this at any time of your choosing.

Comment: Using the client list command i am able to see the IP,port etc details of only the azure web app which leverage this azure Redis Cache but during the development phase i tried accessing the azure Redis cache from my work station VM and i find no details of that and also regarding the ports usually the application communicates using 6379 and 6380 but i see different ports in the retrieved list such as 53019 , 55295 etc

Comment: The ports represent the source ports on the client. The IP address should would what your cache sees. It could represent the gateway that your network exposes. 

id=2195000 addr=71.197.183.40:22643 fd=21 name=SomeName age=203 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 ow=0 owmem=0 events=r cmd=set numops=5582

71.197.183.40 is the public IP address that the cache sees. SomeName represents the name of the connection. 22643 represents the source port on the client which connects to destination port 6379 or 6380 on the cache.